# unable to open http web console for tomato OS using reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, router, ssh-tunnel, tomato

I have a tomato OS on my router. as the router is bedind a NAT, so i cannot access it using port forwarding (dont want to) , or any other way, the only way is to use ssh reverse tunnel. so i tried this command to create ssh tunnel to port 80 , so i can access the tomato OS web console from remote location .

> ssh -f -N -T -R 6680:localhost:80 95.9.9.9

but when i try to access the server from 95.9.9.9 on its http://localhost:6680 , i get connection reset, empty response or other errors.

But when i try to reverse tunnel port 22, it works fine, like this, when i try to ssh to localhost on port 6677 , it works fine.

> ssh -f -N -T -R 6677:localhost:22 95.9.9.9

Here is screenshot of error i get when i access http for tomato OS

http://prntscr.com/mg4nc6